# list operations in python to combine

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a scenario where I have two lists l1 & l2 as mentioned below:

```
l1 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'state': 0}, {'app_id': 1036, 'state': 1}, {'app_id': 1039, 'state': 0},{'app_id': 1030, 'state': 0}]

l2 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'name': ABC}, {'app_id': 1036, 'name': CDE}, {'app_id': 1039, 'name': XYZ},{'app_id': 1030, 'name': JKL}]
```

I am trying to check in this two list whether the `app_id` is common in both the lists if common then add the `name` value as well in the third list, so the desired output should be something like this.

```
l3 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'name': ABC, 'state': 0}, {'app_id': 1036, 'name': CDE, 'state': 1}, {'app_id': 1039, 'name': XYZ, 'state': 0},{'app_id': 1030, 'name': JKL, 'state': 0}]
```

This is what I have tried and looks like the approach is wrong.

```
for key in l1:
    temp=key['app_id']
    for keynd in l2:
        if keynd[app_id]==temp:
            l3.append(keynd['name'])
```

Can someone help me here on how to achieve this ?

Comment: What, *specifically*, makes you think "looks like the approach is wrong"?

Comment: Are your lists actually complete (have the same ids) and perfectly aligned (same id at same position)? Your description implies otherwise, but your example data fits this.

Comment: It can be different as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is currently ambiguous:

- what to do with elements of l1 not present in l2? I shall assume ignore them
- what to do with elements of l2 not present in l1? I shall assume ignore them
- what to do if an app_id from l1 is present more than once in l2? I shall assume use any and shall use last

Searching a dict is generally faster than iterating a list, so I shall build an auxilliary mapping `app_id`=>`name` from l2, and build a copy of `l1` containing only `app_id` present in `l2`, and then append the name from the auxilliary mapping:

```
aux = {it['app_id']: it['name'] for it in l2}
l3 = [it.copy() for it in l1 if it['app_id'] in aux]
for it in l3:
    it['name'] = aux[it['app_id']]
```

it gives for `l3`: `[{'app_id': 9833, 'state': 0, 'name': 'ABC'}, {'app_id': 1036, 'state': 1, 'name': 'CDE'}, {'app_id': 1039, 'state': 0, 'name': 'XYZ'}, {'app_id': 1030, 'state': 0, 'name': 'JKL'}]` without needing nested loops.

Comment: l1 and l2 will have same elements with respect to `app_id`
and there will be no duplication of `app_id`
is your code still valid in that case ?

Comment: @Thomas There is no contradiction with my assumption, so my code should be valid.

Comment: but the order of l1 and l2 elements can be different, that would not affect this ?

Comment: @Thomas: I have made no assumption on the order of the elements of l1 and l2, and my code guarantees that the order in l3 will be the order from l1.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the names are also strings.
This should work:

```
l1 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'state': 0}, {'app_id': 1036, 'state': 1}, {'app_id': 1039, 'state': 0},{'app_id': 1030, 'state': 0}]
l2 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'name': 'ABC'}, {'app_id': 1036, 'name': 'CDE'}, {'app_id': 1039, 'name': 'XYZ'}, {'app_id': 1030, 'name': 'JKL'}]
l3 = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i]['app_id'] == l2[i]['app_id']:
        l3.append({'app_id': l1[i]['app_id'], 'name': l2[i]['name'], 'state': l1[i]['state']})

print(l3)
```

Comment: This is needlessly slower (due to not storing the l1 Id) and more complicated (due to indexing via range instead of direct iteration) than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: merging them using dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'state': 0}, {'app_id': 1036, 'state': 1}, {'app_id': 1039, 'state': 0},{'app_id': 1030, 'state': 0}]
l2 = [{'app_id': 9833, 'name': 'ABC'}, {'app_id': 1036, 'name': 'CDE'}, {'app_id': 1039, 'name': 'XYZ'},{'app_id': 1030, 'name': 'JKL'}]
L1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
L2 = pd.DataFrame(l2)
print(pd.merge(L1, L2, on = 'app_id').to_dict(orient = 'records'))
```

output:

```
[{'app_id': 9833, 'name': 'ABC', 'state': 0},
 {'app_id': 1036, 'name': 'CDE', 'state': 1},
 {'app_id': 1039, 'name': 'XYZ', 'state': 0},
 {'app_id': 1030, 'name': 'JKL', 'state': 0}]
```